Porque mi algoritmo Negamax no funciona?
estoy intentando hacer un bot de ajedrez con el algoritmo Negamax pero no funciona. Paso la función principal que es moverNegaMaxAlphaBeta() y las funciones de posiblesMovimientos() y calcularValorTablero(). La función posiblesMovimientos() bàsicamente calcula los movimientos posibles de la pieza seleccionada, y calcularValorTablero() calcula el valor total del tablero según las piezas que hay, si la pieza es negra, el valor se suma y si es blanca el valor se resta. Para calcular el valor del rey he puesto que valga más el rey que está moviendo porque sino se dejaba matar, y la otra opción era asignarle valor 0 y que puntue cuando se tenga al rey en jaque, pero entonces el código tardaba mucho tiempo y no es útil. Por cierto, perdonen mi código porque soy nuevo en esto, si necesitan algo más diganme y lo comparto. Muchas gracias.
def posiblesMovimientos(self,fila,columna,tablero):
    pieza = tablero[fila][columna][1] #peon, caballo, torre...
    color = tablero[fila][columna][0]
    movimientosPosibles = []
    self.enroqueCorto = False
    self.enroqueLargo = False

    
    if pieza == 'P':
        if color == 'b':
            try:
                if tablero[fila-1][columna] == '--':
                    if (fila == 6) and (tablero[fila-2][columna] == '--'):  #aun no se ha movido el peon
                        movimientosPosibles.append((fila-2,columna))
                    movimientosPosibles.append((fila-1,columna))
            except:
                pass
            try:
                if tablero[fila-1][columna-1][0] == 'n':
                    movimientosPosibles.append((fila-1,columna-1))
            except:
                pass
            try:
                if tablero[fila-1][columna+1][0] == 'n':
                    movimientosPosibles.append((fila-1,columna+1))
            except:
                pass
        else:
            try:
                if tablero[fila+1][columna] == '--':
                    if (fila == 1) and (tablero[fila+2][columna] == '--'):
                        movimientosPosibles.append((fila+2,columna))
                    movimientosPosibles.append((fila+1,columna))
            except:
                pass
            try:
                if tablero[fila+1][columna-1][0] == 'b':
                    movimientosPosibles.append((fila+1,columna-1))
            except:
                pass
            try:
                if tablero[fila+1][columna+1][0] == 'b':
                    movimientosPosibles.append((fila+1,columna+1))
            except:
                pass
    elif pieza == 'T':
        for i in range(1,8): #para abajo
            movimientosPosibles.append((fila+i,columna))
            try:
                if tablero[fila+i][columna] != '--':
                    break
            except:
                pass
        for i in range(1,8): #para arriba    
            movimientosPosibles.append((fila-i,columna))
            try:
                if tablero[fila-i][columna] != '--':
                    break
            except:
                pass
        for i in range(1,8): #para derecha    
            movimientosPosibles.append((fila,columna+i))
            try:
                if tablero[fila][columna+i] != '--':
                    break
            except:
                pass
        for i in range(1,8): #para izquierda    
            movimientosPosibles.append((fila,columna-i))
            try:
                if tablero[fila][columna-i] != '--':
                    break
            except:
                pass
    elif pieza == 'C':
        movimientosPosibles.append((fila-2,columna-1))
        movimientosPosibles.append((fila-2,columna+1))
        movimientosPosibles.append((fila-1,columna+2))
        movimientosPosibles.append((fila+1,columna+2))
        movimientosPosibles.append((fila+2,columna+1))
        movimientosPosibles.append((fila+2,columna-1))
        movimientosPosibles.append((fila+1,columna-2))
        movimientosPosibles.append((fila-1,columna-2))
       
    elif pieza == 'A':
        for i in range(1,8): #para abajo derecha
            movimientosPosibles.append((fila+i,columna+i))
            try:
                if tablero[fila+i][columna+i] != '--':
                    break
            except:
                pass
        for i in range(1,8): #para abajo izquierda
            movimientosPosibles.append((fila+i,columna-i))
            try:
                if tablero[fila+i][columna-i] != '--':
                    break
            except:
                pass
        for i in range(1,8): #para arriba derecha
            movimientosPosibles.append((fila-i,columna+i))
            try:
                if tablero[fila-i][columna+i] != '--':
                    break
            except:
                pass
        for i in range(1,8): #para arriba izquierda
            movimientosPosibles.append((fila-i,columna-i))
            try:
                if tablero[fila-i][columna-i] != '--':
                    break
            except:
                pass
    elif pieza == 'K':
        movimientosPosibles.append((fila-1,columna-1))
        movimientosPosibles.append((fila-1,columna))
        movimientosPosibles.append((fila-1,columna+1))
        movimientosPosibles.append((fila,columna-1))
        movimientosPosibles.append((fila,columna+1))
        movimientosPosibles.append((fila+1,columna-1))
        movimientosPosibles.append((fila+1,columna))
        movimientosPosibles.append((fila+1,columna+1))
        #Enroque corto
        no_movido_blanco_corto = False
        no_movido_blanco_largo = False
        no_movido_negro_corto = False
        no_movido_negro_largo = False
        if color == 'b':
            for tablero2 in self.historial:
                tablero2 = eval(tablero2)
                #print(tablero)
                if (tablero2[7][4] == 'bK') and (tablero2[7][7] == 'bT'):
                    no_movido_blanco_corto = True
                else:
                    no_movido_blanco_corto = False
                    break
            if (no_movido_blanco_corto == True) and (tablero[7][5] == '--') and (tablero[7][6] == '--'):
                self.enroqueCorto = True
            #print('bc:',no_movido_blanco_corto)
        else:
            for tablero2 in self.historial:
                tablero2 = eval(tablero2)
                if (tablero2[0][4] == 'nK') and (tablero2[0][7] == 'nT'):
                    no_movido_negro_corto = True
                else:
                    no_movido_negro_corto = False
                    break
            if (no_movido_negro_corto == True) and (tablero[0][5] == '--') and (tablero[0][6] == '--'):
                self.enroqueCorto = True
            #print('nc:',no_movido_negro_corto)
        #Enroque largo
        if color == 'b':
            for tablero2 in self.historial:
                tablero2 = eval(tablero2)
                if (tablero2[7][4] == 'bK') and (tablero2[7][0] == 'bT'):
                    no_movido_blanco_largo = True
                else:
                    no_movido_blanco_largo = False
                    break
            if (no_movido_blanco_largo == True) and (tablero[7][1] == '--') and (tablero[7][2] == '--') and (tablero[7][3] == '--'):
                self.enroqueLargo = True
            #print('bl:',no_movido_blanco_largo)
        else:
            for tablero2 in self.historial:
                tablero2 = eval(tablero2)
                if (tablero2[0][4] == 'nK') and (tablero2[0][0] == 'nT'):
                    no_movido_negro_largo = True
                else:
                    no_movido_negro_largo = False
                    break
            if (no_movido_negro_largo == True) and (tablero[0][1] == '--') and (tablero[0][2] == '--') and (tablero[0][3] == '--'):
                self.enroqueLargo = True
            #print('nl:',no_movido_negro_largo)
        
    elif pieza == 'Q':
        #Torre
        for i in range(1,8): #para abajo
            movimientosPosibles.append((fila+i,columna))
            try:
                if tablero[fila+i][columna] != '--':
                    break
            except:
                pass
        for i in range(1,8): #para arriba    
            movimientosPosibles.append((fila-i,columna))
            try:
                if tablero[fila-i][columna] != '--':
                    break
            except:
                pass
        for i in range(1,8): #para derecha    
            movimientosPosibles.append((fila,columna+i))
            try:
                if tablero[fila][columna+i] != '--':
                    break
            except:
                pass
        for i in range(1,8): #para izquierda    
            movimientosPosibles.append((fila,columna-i))
            try:
                if tablero[fila][columna-i] != '--':
                    break
            except:
                pass
        #Alfil
        for i in range(1,8): #para abajo derecha
            movimientosPosibles.append((fila+i,columna+i))
            try:
                if tablero[fila+i][columna+i] != '--':
                    break
            except:
                pass
        for i in range(1,8): #para abajo izquierda
            movimientosPosibles.append((fila+i,columna-i))
            try:
                if tablero[fila+i][columna-i] != '--':
                    break
            except:
                pass
        for i in range(1,8): #para arriba derecha
            movimientosPosibles.append((fila-i,columna+i))
            try:
                if tablero[fila-i][columna+i] != '--':
                    break
            except:
                pass
        for i in range(1,8): #para arriba izquierda
            movimientosPosibles.append((fila-i,columna-i))
            try:
                if tablero[fila-i][columna-i] != '--':
                    break
            except:
                pass

    movimientosEliminados = []
    for movimiento in movimientosPosibles:
        if (movimiento[0]<0) or (movimiento[0]>7) or (movimiento[1]<0) or (movimiento[1]>7):
            movimientosEliminados.append(movimiento)
        
    for movimientoEliminado in movimientosEliminados:
        movimientosPosibles.remove(movimientoEliminado)
    
    movimientosEliminados = []
    
    for movimiento in movimientosPosibles:
        if color == 'b':
            if tablero[movimiento[0]][movimiento[1]][0] == 'b':
                movimientosEliminados.append(movimiento)
        elif color == 'n':
            if tablero[movimiento[0]][movimiento[1]][0] == 'n':
                movimientosEliminados.append(movimiento)
    
    for movimientoEliminado in movimientosEliminados:
        movimientosPosibles.remove(movimientoEliminado)
    
    return movimientosPosibles

def calcularValorTablero(self,tablero,mueveblanco):
    valor = 0
    
    #valorPiezas = {'P':1,'T':5,'C':3,'A':3,'Q':9,'K':999}


    if mueveblanco:
        valorPiezas = {'P':1,'T':5,'C':3,'A':3,'Q':9,'bK':9999,'nK':999}
    else:
        valorPiezas = {'P':1,'T':5,'C':3,'A':3,'Q':9,'bK':999,'nK':9999}

    for fila in range(8):
        for columna in range(8):
            pieza = tablero[fila][columna]
            if pieza != '--':
                valorPosicional = 0
                if pieza[1] != 'K':
                    valorPosicional = self.scorePosicion[pieza][fila][columna]
                    if pieza[0] == 'b':
                        valor = valor - valorPiezas[pieza[1]] - valorPosicional
                    elif pieza[0] == 'n':
                        valor = valor + valorPiezas[pieza[1]] + valorPosicional
                else:
                    if pieza[0] == 'b':
                        valor = valor - valorPiezas[pieza]
                    elif pieza[0] == 'n':
                        valor = valor + valorPiezas[pieza]
        
    return valor


def moverNegaMaxAlphaBeta(self,multiplicador,tablero,depth,alpha,beta,mueveBlanco):#multiplicador darà valor a la puntuacion según el turno: 1 si mueve negro -1 si mueve blanco
    
    self.contador += 1

    if depth == 0:
        return multiplicador*self.calcularValorTablero(tablero,mueveBlanco)
    
    maxScore = -99999999
    filas = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
    columnas = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
    random.shuffle(filas)
    random.shuffle(columnas)

    for fila in filas:
        for columna in columnas:
            if multiplicador == 1:
                if tablero[fila][columna][0] == 'n':
                    movimientosPosibles = self.posiblesMovimientos(fila,columna,tablero).copy()
                    for movimiento in movimientosPosibles:
                        tablero2 = self.simularMovimiento(fila,columna,movimiento[0],movimiento[1],tablero)
                        score = -self.moverNegaMaxAlphaBeta(-multiplicador,tablero2,depth-1,-beta,-alpha,mueveBlanco)
                        if score > maxScore:
                            maxScore = score
                            if depth == self.depth:
                                self.nextMove = ((fila,columna),movimiento)
                        if maxScore > alpha:
                            alpha = maxScore
                        if alpha >= beta:
                            break
                    
            else:
                if tablero[fila][columna][0] == 'b':
                    movimientosPosibles = self.posiblesMovimientos(fila,columna,tablero).copy()
                    for movimiento in movimientosPosibles:
                        tablero2 = self.simularMovimiento(fila,columna,movimiento[0],movimiento[1],tablero)
                        score = -self.moverNegaMaxAlphaBeta(-multiplicador,tablero2,depth-1,-beta,-alpha,mueveBlanco)
                        if score > maxScore:
                            maxScore = score
                            if depth == self.depth:
                                self.nextMove = ((fila,columna),movimiento)
                        if maxScore > alpha:
                            alpha = maxScore
                        if alpha >= beta:
                            break
    
    return maxScore

En la imagen de debajo está el tablero y le toca mover a Negro. El movimiento que hace el algoritmo es mover el Alfil para comerse al peón de encima de la torre lo qual es un movimiento que no es bueno porque suma 1 punto del peón pero pierde 3 puntos por el Alfil.


Sería más fácil ayudarte si proporcionas un tablero con una posición específica y la/las movidas esperadas a partir de esa posición. Decir "no me funciona" sin explicar el resultado deseado en términos ajedrecisticos nos deja en total oscuridad.

Ok, he añadido un ejemplo del fallo del programa.

¿A qué profundidad de búsqueda lo estás ejecutando en esa prueba que compartes?

A una profundidad de 3

Como lo veo podrá ser a causa del "horizon effect" https://www.chessprogramming.org/Horizon_Effect. Haciendo un par de líneas mentales en profundidad 3 tenemos: nivel 1. Negras capturan dama blanca, nivel 2 blancas capturan con caballo o rey, nivel 3 negras capturan al peon de a2 y negras tienen ventaja. Caso 2: nivel 1 negras capturan el peón de a2 , nivel 2 blancas capturan con torre o caballo, nivel 3 negras capturan la dama blanca. En ambos casos al finalizar el nivel 3 la evaluación es a favor de las negras porque hasta ahí llega la búsqueda. Prueba subiendo la profundidad a 4 o 5.

Esto no resuelve el problema planteado, pero ofrece un nuevo enfoque que posiblemente te facilite la compresión y depuración del código.
La idea es establecer una jerarquía de clases, partiendo por la clase base Pieza, con los atributos y métodos compartidos por todas las piezas del tablero:
class Pieza:
    def __init__(self, color, fila, columna, valor):
        self.color = color
        self.fila = fila
        self.columna = columna
        self.valor = valor

    def mover(self, fila, columna):
        self.fila = fila
        self.columna = columna

    def posiblesMovientos(self):
        return []

De esa clase derivamos todas las demás (Peon, Caballo, ...). Por ejemplo, la clase Torre queda así:
class Torre(Pieza):
    def __init__(self, color, fila, columna):
        super().__init__(color, fila, columna, 5)

    def posiblesMovientos(self):
        fila = self.fila
        columna = self.columna

        movimientosPosibles = []
        for i in range(8):
            if i != fila:
                movimientosPosibles.append((i, columna))
            if i != columna:
                movimientosPosibles.append((fila, i))
        return movimientosPosibles

Así, el calcular una movida, no necesitas saber con que pieza en particular estas trabajando. Por ejemplo, si tomas la pieza de la segunda fila (desde arriba), tercera columna, puedes calcular sus posibles movimientos simplemente llamando al método:
pieza = tablero.tablero[1][3]
print(pieza.posiblesMovimientos())

lo que da
[(2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4)]

Así mismo definimos una clase Tablero, que tiene el tablero con sus piezas y métodos para calcular su valor.
Espero que te sirva, aunque puede que tengas que hacer ajustes por aquí y por allá.
Código
class Pieza:
    def __init__(self, color, fila, columna, valor):
        self.color = color
        self.fila = fila
        self.columna = columna
        self.valor = valor

    def mover(self, fila, columna):
        self.fila = fila
        self.columna = columna

    def posiblesMovimientos(self):
        return []

class Peon(Pieza):
    def __init__(self, color, fila, columna):
        super().__init__(color, fila, columna, 1)

    def posiblesMovimientos(self):
        fila = self.fila
        columna = self.columna

        movimientosPosibles = []
        if self.color == 'b' and fila > 0:
            movimientosPosibles.append((fila - 1, columna - 1))
            movimientosPosibles.append((fila - 1, columna))
            movimientosPosibles.append((fila - 1, columna + 1))
        elif self.color == 'n' and fila < 7:
            movimientosPosibles.append((fila + 1, columna - 1))
            movimientosPosibles.append((fila + 1, columna))
            movimientosPosibles.append((fila + 1, columna + 1))
        return movimientosPosibles


class Alfil(Pieza):
    def __init__(self, color, fila, columna):
        super().__init__(color, fila, columna, 3)

    def posiblesMovimientos(self, fila, columna):
        movimientosPosibles = []

        i = fila + 1
        j = columna + 1
        while i < 8 and j < 8:
            movimientosPosibles.append((i, j))
            i += 1
            j += 1

        i = fila + 1
        j = columna - 1
        while i >= 0 and j < 8:
            movimientosPosibles.append((i, j))
            i -= 1
            j += 1

        i = fila - 1
        j = columna + 1
        while i >= 0 and j < 8:
            movimientosPosibles.append((i, j))
            i -= 1
            j += 1

        i = fila - 1
        j = columna - 1
        while i >= 0 and j >= 0:
            movimientosPosibles.append((i, j))
            i -= 1
            j -= 1
        return movimientosPosibles

class Caballo(Pieza):
    def __init__(self, color, fila, columna):
        super().__init__(color, fila, columna, 3)

    def posiblesMovimientos(self):
        fila = self.fila
        columna = self.columna

        movimientosPosibles = []
        if fila > 2:
            if columna > 0:
                movimientosPosibles.append((fila - 2, columna - 1))
            if columna < 7:
                movimientosPosibles.append((fila - 2, columna + 1))

        if fila > 1:
            if columna < 6:
                movimientosPosibles.append((fila - 1, columna + 2))
            if columna > 2:
                movimientosPosibles.append((fila - 1, columna - 2))

        if fila < 7:
            if columna < 6:
                movimientosPosibles.append((fila + 1, columna + 2))
            if columna > 2:
                movimientosPosibles.append((fila + 1, columna - 2))

        if fila < 6:
            if columna < 7:
                movimientosPosibles.append((fila + 2, columna + 1))
            if columna > 1:
                movimientosPosibles.append((fila + 2, columna - 1))

        return movimientosPosibles

class Torre(Pieza):
    def __init__(self, color, fila, columna):
        super().__init__(color, fila, columna, 5)

    def posiblesMovimientos(self):
        fila = self.fila
        columna = self.columna

        movimientosPosibles = []
        for i in range(8):
            if i != fila:
                movimientosPosibles.append((i, columna))
            if i != columna:
                movimientosPosibles.append((fila, i))
        return movimientosPosibles

class King(Pieza):
    def __init__(self, color, fila, columna):
        super().__init__(color, fila, columna, 0)
        self.enroque = False
        self.enroque_permitido = True

    def posiblesMovimientos(self):
        fila = self.fila
        columna = self.columna

        movimientosPosibles = []
        for i in range(fila - 1, fila + 2):
            if i != fila and 0 <= i <= 7:
                movimientosPosibles.append((i, columna))
        for i in range(columna - 1, columna + 2):
            if i != columna and 0 <= i <= 7:
                movimientosPosibles.append((fila, i))
        return movimientosPosibles

class Queen(Pieza):
    def __init__(self, color, fila, columna):
        super().__init__(color, fila, columna, 9)

    def posiblesMovimientos(self, fila, columna):
        fila = self.fila
        columna = self.columna

        torre = Torre(self.color, self.fila, self.columna)
        alfil = Alfil(self.color, self.fila, self.columna)
        movimientosPosibles = torre.posiblesMovimientos().extend(alfil.posiblesMovimientos())
        return movimientosPosibles

negro = 'n'
blanco = 'b'

class Tablero:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tablero = []
        fila = [Torre(negro, 0, 0), Caballo(negro, 0,1), Alfil(negro, 0, 2),
                Queen(negro, 0, 3), King(negro, 0, 4), Alfil(negro, 0, 5),
                Caballo(negro, 0, 6), Torre(negro, 0, 7)]
        self.tablero.append(fila)

        fila = []
        for i in range(8):
            fila.append(Peon(negro, 1, i))
        self.tablero.append(fila)

        self.tablero.append([None] * 8)
        self.tablero.append([None] * 8)
        self.tablero.append([None] * 8)
        self.tablero.append([None] * 8)

        fila = []
        for i in range(8):
            fila.append(Peon(blanco, 6, i))
        self.tablero.append(fila)

        fila = [Torre(blanco, 7, 0), Caballo(blanco, 7,1), Alfil(blanco, 7, 2),
                Queen(blanco, 7, 3), King(blanco, 7, 4), Alfil(blanco, 7, 5),
                Caballo(blanco, 7, 6), Torre(blanco, 7, 7)]
        self.tablero.append(fila)

    def calcularValor(self, color):
        valor = 0

        for fila in range(8):
            for columna in range(8):
                pieza = self.tablero[fila][columna]
                if pieza:
                    valorPieza = pieza.valor if pieza.color == color else -pieza.valor
                    if isinstance(pieza, King):
                        valorPosicional = 0
                    else:
                        valorPosicional = 1 # self.scorePosicion[pieza][fila][columna]
                    if pieza.color == color:
                        valor += valorPieza + valorPosicional
                    else:
                        valor -= (valorPieza + valorPosicional)

        return valor

tablero = Tablero()

pieza = tablero.tablero[1][3]
print(pieza.posiblesMovimientos())


Muchas gracias!!!
